# Adding an image and an address on every page - no new packages

Tags: tikz-pgf, everypage

I am producing a `LaTeX` template for our corporate branding.  This requires the university logo on the top right of every page, and the address on the bottom right of every page except the title page.

I want to minimise the need for new packages to be installed on the fragmented systems we use.  As such I want to avoid answers that have been given on similar questions - I want to avoid eso-pic and fancyhdr.

Is there anyway to do this without loading any new packages(tikz is allowed)?

Comment: `fancyhdr` is just one package and it requires only a few commands.

Comment: `fancyhdr` is indeed the best solution, in my opinion.

Comment: I guess there is a `latex` macro that runs on each page that I could edit...  Not sure what or where though.

Comment: This question might have been marked as a duplicate but the answers given here are not duplicates of the answers to the referenced question.

Comment: As I do not want to use new packages such as fancyhdr and eso-pics, I cannot see how it is a duplicate of previous questions which allowed any answer.

Comment: @adunaic: Well, you wrote, that you don't want 'new' packages. This is not really clear (although you have changed your question in between :-( )

Comment: @ChristianHupfer:  I was trying to clarify this.  I only editted the question, as that was my interpretation to the instructions given "please edit this question to explain how it is different".

When I changed the headings to be a different style / colour I used the \renewcommand\section{\@startsection{section} command so that I did not have to load an additional (new) package such as titlesec.  I was hoping for a similar solution.

Comment: You don't want 'new' package but ***TikZ*** is allowed??!! You can, of course, avoid the need to load a package by simply duplicating its code in your class or package. However, there are obviously excellent reasons not to do this.

Comment: You could do this, I guess, by creating a new page style using LaTeX's basic facilities for this. It is harder than using a package, obviously, but should be doable. At least, I'm assuming that the logo is available in a font format (postscript type1 or metafont). Otherwise, I don't see how you can do it without additional packages. But I can't really see why TikZ is OK but not its dependencies.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "not its dependencies".   I want to minimise the need for new packages, as getting systems to push new packages out is difficult, and I am not sure what packages are there by default - I know tikz is in all the installs that we have.   If there is a way to find out what the default or core packages are, that would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fancyhdr` is one of the possibilities to achieve some header/footer content on every (specific) page.

Use `fancyhead[R]` and `fancyfoot[R]` for content that should appear on the right of every page in the `fancy` pagestyle.

Most likely, the `headheight` value must be changed to the real settings, this depends on the size of the graphics, for example!

The titlepage is by default `plain` or `empty`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[headheight=65pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{ente}} % top graphics
\fancyfoot[R]{\begin{tabular}{l}Ministry of Silly Walks\\ Bakerstreet 150 \\Drop-Box London\end{tabular}} % Address box

\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\author{Ann Elk}
\title{Theory of Brontosaurs}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

Here's the file [ente.jpg](https://i.imgur.com/UF48qpT.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Thanks,  I will consider this one.  I was trying to avoid new packages, even if it means the coding the template is harder.  I guess fancyhdr is standard enough these days though.

Answer (score 3):

This uses the `everypage` package, and introduces the macro

```
\everyxy{<x-page location>}{<y-page location>}{<content>}
```

The location is measured with respect to the top left corner of the paper.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% THESE ARE LaTeX DEFAULTS; CAN CHANGE IF NEEDED.
\def\PageTopMargin{1in}
\def\PageLeftMargin{1in}
\newcommand\everyxy[3]{%
 \AddEverypageHook{\smash{\hspace*{\dimexpr-\PageLeftMargin-\hoffset+#1\relax}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\PageTopMargin+\voffset-#2\relax}{#3}}}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-6]
\everyxy{7in}{1.2in}{\includegraphics[height=1in]{example-image-a}}
\everyxy{7in}{10.5in}{\parbox[b]{1in}{XYZ University\\101 S. Main St.\\Anytown, USA}}
\lipsum[7-10]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here, I invoke it on page 2, so that is where the images begin.

Comment: @StevenBSegletes should it be example-image-a or `A`

Comment: @jsbibra It should be lower case...on my system, it works either way, but I was later corrected that the actual file uses lower case in its name.  I will edit the answer here.

Answer (score 2):

As you want to minimise the number of packages please consider the `memoir` class which has built in support for headers\footers. For example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makepagestyle{aduanic} % your page style
\makeevenhead{aduanic}{}{}{Your logo} % specify the contents
\makeoddhead{aduanic}{}{}{Your logo}
\makeevenfoot{aduanic}{}{}{Address}
\makeoddfoot{aduanic}{{}{}{Address}

\pagestyle{aduanic} % use the aduanic pagestyle

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty} % empty pagestyle for the title 

TITLE

\clearpage

\lipsum % the text with the aduanic pagestyle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was wanting to find a way to do this so that the users can still choose the document class they want to use.  Whilst memoir is a great suggestion, it unfortunately does not let the user choose which class they want.